# Octave installing package fails on mac osx (Segmentation fault)

Tags: macos, package, octave

I am trying to install general package (general-1.3.4.tar.gz) to octave 3.8.0. Im using mac osx Yosemite. Im getting segmentation fault. This occurs no matter which package I try to install (for example singal). I have xcode and command line tools installed. All help will be appreciated.

Here is the error i get when executing pkg install general-1.3.4.tar.gz:

```
octave:3> pkg install general-1.3.4.tar.gz
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0: line 512: 15159 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe -Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread SHA1.cc -o SHA1.o
make: *** [SHA1.oct] Error 139
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0 SHA1.cc
pkg: error running `make' for the general package.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 82, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9*
```

Comment: @carandraug: I am having a similar issue. Did you manage to figure out the problem?

Comment: @Sid I don't have that problem, I only edited the question because the errors were incorrectly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a workaround from other sites on the web:

I was having the same issue when trying to install the Octave Signal Package without success. The following finally appears to be working.

1. code-select --install from the Terminal window to install the command line tools
2. Install MacPorts for Mac. This is a standard installer that you can download from Macports.
3. sudo port install gcc48 --> This is a Fortran compiler, which is necessary for installing octave-general
4. sudo port install octave-general
5. sudo port install octave-control
6. sudo port install octave-signal