# mkoctfile Segmentation Fault

Tags: octave

I'm trying to compile an [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles.html) mex file in Octave and get the following error that I don't understand and can't find where to go for more information:

```
octave:8> mkoctfile -v --mex hello_oct.cpp
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0: line 512: 15840 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe -Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I. hello_oct.cpp -o hello_oct.o
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe -Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I. hello_oct.cpp -o hello_oct.o
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
```

The same error occurs without the `--mex` option and across different source files. I'm running Octave 3.8.0 on OS X Yosemite. I don't believe I need to install any packages in Octave to create .mex or .oct files, but let me know if I do. I'd appreciate any explanation behind the error or suggestions of where to look for solutions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155617/octave-installing-package-fails-on-mac-osx-segmentation-fault) is a related question but appears in a different context it seems.

Comment: You can make `mkoctfile` more verbose with the `-v` option: `mkoctfile -v --mex hello_oct.cpp`

Comment: @ederag: Thanks, I've updated the question with the verbose output but it appears to give hardly any extra information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the 3.8.0 binary. Reinstalling with homebrew fixed the issue.