# octave 3.8 odepkg installation in Mac throws segmentation fault

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, octave

When I try to install Octave odepkg in Mac OSX, it gives the following error. I have Xcode installed. Anybody know the reason for the error?

```
pkg install odepkg -forge
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0: 
line 512: 28409 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe -Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread odepkg_octsolver_mebdfdae.cc -o odepkg_octsolver_mebdfdae.o
make: *** [odepkg_octsolver_mebdfdae.o] Error 139
Unpacking external packages: hairer.tgz
Unpacking external packages: cash.tgz
Unpacking external packages: daskr.tgz
Applying patches from file: hairer.diff
Applying patches from file: cash.diff
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file cash/mebdfdae.f
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file cash/mebdfi.f
Applying patches from file: daskr.diff
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file daskr/ddaskr.f
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file daskr/dlinpk.f
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0 -c odepkg_octsolver_mebdfdae.cc -o odepkg_octsolver_mebdfdae.o

pkg: error running `make' for the odepkg package.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 82, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9
```

Comment: I edited the title and question to improve readability and updated the tags to include relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of [mkoctfile Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358350/mkoctfile-segmentation-fault). You really should mention how you've installed Octave from which source. Is it this http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Binary_installer_for_OSX_10.9.1? Perhaps you should try homebrew instead.